# .applying (transform) unresolved

Tags: swift, swift3

Why is .applying (transform) unresolved?
Also why there is no `imageByApplying` anymore?

```
let output = filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform)
        if (output != nil) {
            return UIImage(CIImage: output!)
}
        return nil;
}
```

Comment: I can't actually test this code without a minimal, verifiable example. Without it, I can only provide general hints at how to improve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unresolved identifier is probably `UIImage(CIImage`. In Swift 3 it's `UIImage(ciImage`

Better optional bind `outputImage`.

If the check succeeds the transform (which does not return an optional) will be applied

```
if let output = filter?.outputImage {
    return UIImage(ciImage: output.applying(transform))
}
return nil
```

or preferable

```
guard let output = filter?.outputImage else { return nil }
return UIImage(ciImage: output.applying(transform))
```

`applying(_` is the Swift 3 syntax of former `imageByApplying`

Comment: ’@IBAction func generateQrcode(_ sender: Any) {
        imageDisplay.image = generateQrcodeFromstring(string: "text!")
    }
    func generateQrcodeFromstring(string :String) -> UIImage?{
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        let filter = CIFilter(name:  "CIQRCodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        _ = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
        if let output = filter?.outputImage {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output.applying(transform))
        }
        return nil}
} ->transform still check not succeed

Answer (score 1):

Never check for `nil` only to then force unwrap. Just use conditional binding:

```
if let output = filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
    return UIImage(CIImage: output)
}
    return nil;
}
```

Or if you really want to get fancy:

```
return filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform).map(UIImage.init(CIImage:))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! but transform still didn't check succeed@@

Comment: @benwang "transform still didn't check succeed@@" what?